# is there some way I can view a SQLite db?

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm encountering a very odd behavior where a SQLite db entry is not throwing any exceptions, but when I later do a select where I search for the row I have inserted, it doesn't turn up.

I'm at a loss as to how to debug this, as I have no way to verify that the insert is actually working.  I've examined all the SQL calls and they look right, so now I'm just stuck.

Is there a phone resident db tool of some sort that I can use to view the db?  Or an ADB command line SQL thing of some sort?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  ADB will let you examine databases from the shell.

See this page on the Android site:  http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#sqlite

Answer (score 1):

If you want this for development - you can use  [MOTODEV Studio](http://developer.motorola.com/docstools/motodevstudio/) from Motorola It has UI for SQlite. Its free!

Comment: thanks for the mention. Yes, you can use MOTODEV Studio to view a database on the emulator or a developer/rooted phone. If the database is on a commercial phone, you will need to store it to the SD card on the phone explicitly with the CreateDatabase() API using '/sdcard/myfolder/mydb.db'.

Answer (score 1):

Pull out the db file from the emulator. Open it with SQLite Browser.

And there are adb commands:

```
$ adb -s emulator-5554 shell
# sqlite3 /data/data/com.example.google.rss.rssexample/databases/rssitems.db
SQLite version 3.3.12
Enter ".help" for instructions
.... enter commands, then quit...
sqlite> .exit
```